# For regular stochastic matrices, what power suffices to make it positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes

Suppose $P$ is a $N\times N$ non-negative matrix whose rows each sum to 1 (i.e. $P$ is stochastic). Suppose further that we know $\exists m$ such that $P^m$ has all positive entries (i.e. $P$ is regular).

> Is there an upper bound one can give for what $m$ is?

For example, I recall hearing from somewhere that $P^{N^2}$ will always be positive and $N^2$ is the best upper bound for $m$. Unfortunately I cannot trace any source saying this. I imagine that showing this will be useful in (brute-force) checking if a stochastic matrix is regular.

I am able to show that if $P^i$ has all positive entries, then so does $P^{i+1}$. As such, I really only need to show that some $m \leq N^2$ does the job.